# What is the ideal expiration time for oauth2 implicit flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, implicit-flow

I understand that the access-tokens are issued with a short expiration time in OAuth2 implicit flow, so that the application is forced to continually refresh them (using iframes or other means), giving the service a chance to revoke an application’s access if needed.

But what is the ideal expiration time? Should it be around 15 mins/more/less?

Comment: It depends on the use case. My bank uses really short expirations (<5 minutes). For non-sensitive web sites, there really is no need for short expirations. I should not be required to reauthenticate while browsing on Nordstrom's website (I should once I hit the shopping payment cart).